# What is the best way to add a global navigation item to Active Admin in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to add a global navigation menu item to my Active Admin installation (next to the 'Dashboard' nav button). Active Admin says this is possible on their site but they do not have any documentation about how to achieve it. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want to add a link to the global navigation that consists of an arbitrary text/link pair. IE, if I wanted to add a link to http://google.com with text "Google" in the global navigation of active admin, how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Google" do
  menu :priority => 1, :label => 'Google' , :url => 'http://google.com'
 end
```

Comment: in newer versions of ActiveAdmin, one can do that. When this question was asked originally the register_page directive did not yet exist in AA.

Answer (score -1):

Only relevant for ActiveAdmin versions <= 0.4 ::  Reading the source of the TabbedNavigation class, there does not seem to be an easy way. If relying on javascript and jquery does not bother you, you could place something similar to this in your application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dashboard').parent().append('<li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>');
});
```

Where do they claim that this would be possible?

Comment: Thanks Sjors, I think this is how I ended up handling it. I had forgotten about this post :) 

On their homepage, Active Admin states this: 
"Global Navigation
Customizable global navigation allows you to create usable admin interfaces for your business." - which I assumed to mean that you could configure the links in the nav bar to anything you want. I guess that must not be the case.

Comment: Or you can add that code to active_admin.js if you don't want it to collide with anything in the rest of the app.